# Is this a proper way to AES encrypt larger file in powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, encryption, powershell-4.0, encryption-symmetric

I've tried first by loading the file content into some variable with `[IO.File]::ReadAllBytes`

But that takes a lot of RAM and it's painfully slow.

So here's what I've got:

```
ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$AES = [System.Security.Cryptography.AES]::Create()
$AES.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::PKCS7
$AES.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
$AES.BlockSize = 128
$AES.KeySize = 256
$AES.GenerateKey()
$AES.GenerateIV()
$Encryptor = $AES.CreateEncryptor()

$File = Get-Item -Path "C:\Myfile.exe"

$InputStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($File, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
$OutputStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream((($File.FullName) + ".AES"), [System.IO.FileMode]::Create, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write)

$CryptoStream = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream($OutputStream, $Encryptor, [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode]::Write)

$InputStream.CopyTo($CryptoStream)
$CryptoStream.Dispose()

$AES.Dispose()
```

It works. However I was wondering if this is how it's supposed to be done. Do I not need to prepend IV to the beginning of the file, or does it happen automatically with the Encryptor?

Thanks for any responses in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use streams and `CopyTo`. Yes, you should probably prefix the IV, no it doesn't do this automatically.

Note that you provide confidentiality, but no authenticity / integrity. This could be fine for encrypting files though.

You have used `Aes.Create()` and indicated the exact mode of operation & padding, which is as it should be.

---

Note that this is not a security review. The destruction of the original file or the use case for encrypting an executable is not considered.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm new to the whole encryption thing, so how would I do this?

`$OutputStream.Write($AES.IV, 0, (($AES.IV).Length))`

Would this work?

Comment: Yes, generally you can just use `Write($AES.IV)` though. Of course, you need to do this *before* you write anything to the crypto-stream, i.e. before the `CopyTo` operation :)

Comment: This seems to work, however I'm having trouble with decryptor.


It actually decrypts the file, but there's encrypted gibberish at the very beginning of file. This is what I've got: https://pastefy.ga/gBX9NPuw

I assume that's the unencrypted IV part, but I don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: Well, you create a file input stream, then you read the IV, and then connect a cryptostream to the input stream, and use `CopyTo` again. I strongly dislike using a cryptostream on the output stream for decryption, it makes zero sense conceptually.

Comment: Thank you, it works like charm now. What do you think is the better way to decrypt? I'm open to suggestions.

And do you mind explaining why it's bad to use cryptostream on the output stream?

Comment: Well, you may for instance want to do separate things with the plaintext after decryption. Or for CTR mode you might want to skip bytes, for instance (not that .NET provides CTR mode *like any other cryptographic library does*). It is also not the opposite of what you do during encryption, and experience shows me that if you do something conceptually wrong, it may bite you in practice in the end. For instance, if you use `Write` then when should the unpadding take place?